# Angular JS directives scope variable relationship

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand the Angualr JS directives. But i am confused with the scopes and relation ship between the parent controller and directives. For example:

1) I inserted the "hello-world" directive (it has its own controller, please check below code) into the "myCtrl", i mean as a child.

2) I have one variable in the directive, "directiveVar" and other variable in the controller, "controllerVar", each has different values.

3) My confusion are as follows:

- As the myCtrl is the parent of the "hello-world" directive, so by default, "hello-world" directive scope can inherit the variables from the controller
- But i can see the child "hello-world" directive variables in the parent too, i mean myCtrl.
- How is this possible, i mean child can inherit parent values but how did the parent can inherit child values?
- What is the use the controller in the directive (I know the reason, but I am confused, i just want some light on that if i am missing anything).

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
angular.module('myapp').directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World<br /> <br />{{color}} <br /> <br /> {{directiveVar}}',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.color = '#0080ff';
        $scope.directiveVar = "I am directive varible";
    },    
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        elem.css('background-color', 'white');
        console.dir(scope);
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.color = "white";
        });
      });
      elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
        elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
    }
  };
});

angular.module('myapp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.color = '#ffb399';
    $scope.controllerVar = "I am controller varible";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="color" placeholder="Enter a color" /> 
  <br />
  <br />
  {{color}}
  <br />
  <br />
  {{directiveVar}}
  <br /> <br /> 
  <hello-world/>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap-contextmenu/contextMenu.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a ton of questions, but let's see if we can address each one.  For further reading [this is a great overview post](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)

**First, Directives MAY or MAY NOT have their own scope.**

They don't automatically get their own scope.  You have to add that as a part of the directive declaration.  Without re-writing someone else's blog post (or the docs), here are some basic rules:

1. Scope : False ( Directive uses its parent scope )
2. Scope : True ( Directive gets it's own scope ... a 'child' scope )
3. Scope : { } ( Directive gets a new isolated scope )

That's about as basic an overview as you need to get around.  One more thing to remember is that a directive gets it's own child scope by default (eg - Scope:true is the default setting).

As I said, that article link at the top is really great.  I don't want to write a book on directive scope, but please comment if you have anything to add as I think a basic directive/scope "overview" post would be handy.

There are a bunch of links that I would add here, but I think [the scope discussion that is most frequently linked](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) is pretty technical and detailed.  Not the world's greatest jumping off point (unless you're into cliff diving).

Comment: thank you, main answer to my question lays in the scope rules. But what is the use of the controller in the directive and can the directive can access rootscope ?

Comment: All scopes (including the ones in your directives) inherit from root. So, yes. As to the purpose of .controller property -- feels like the topic of another question no??  That'd be a good one!